# Keras predict in a process freezes

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, keras

I am trying to make an server which predicts (regression) given a certain input, however when I make a shared keras (with tensorflow backend) file to preload and skip loading the model every time (which would save about 1.8 seconds), and when I try to predict anything from a thread the program just freezes (even though only one thread is accessing it during my test). I know that the tensor is not made for this, however as it is only predicting there should be a workaround for this. I have tried using _make_prediction_function but that did not work.

This is the main function:

```
keras_model = keras_model_for_threads()
def thread_function(conn, addr, alive):
    print('Connected by', addr)
    start = time.time()
    sent = conn.recv(1024)
    x_pred = preproc(sent)
    conn.sendall(keras_model.predict_single(x_pred))
    conn.close()
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = xxxxx
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1000)
print('Ready for listening')
while alive.get():
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    Process(target=thread_function, args=(conn, addr, alive)).start()
```

with the keras_model:

```
class keras_model_for_threads():
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = load_model(model_path)
        self.model._make_predict_function()

    def predict_single(self, x_pred):        
        return self.model.predict(x_pred)
```

Now if I run this normally, it executes and returns a prediction but through the Process with the thread function it freezes on the self.model.predict.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching I found an answer which works, namely making a manager to handle the prediction. This changes the original keras code to:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import Lock

class KerasModelForThreads():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.model = None

    def load_model(self):
        from keras.models import load_model
        self.model = load_model(model_path)

    def predict_single(self, x_pred):
        with self.lock:
            return (self.model.predict(x_pred) + self.const.offset)[0][0]

class KerasManager(BaseManager):
    pass

KerasManager.register('KerasModelForThreads', KerasModelForThreads)
```

And the main code to

```
from keras_for_threads import KerasManager
keras_manager = KerasManager()
keras_manager.start()
keras_model = keras_manager.KerasModelForThreads()
keras_model.load_model()
def thread_function(conn, addr, alive):
    print('Connected by', addr)
    start = time.time()
    sent = conn.recv(1024)
    x_pred = preproc(sent)
    conn.sendall(keras_model.predict_single(x_pred))
    conn.close()
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = xxxxx
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1000)
print('Ready for listening')
while alive.get():
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    Process(target=thread_function, args=(conn, addr, alive)).start()
```

This is a stripped down version (without the Flask stuff, just the keras part) from the github project I found here:https://github.com/Dref360/tuto_keras_web